# an error with java code, maze recursive algorithm

Tags: java, recursion

```
         20 7
         xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxEx
         x     x       xxxx x
         x xxxxx xxxxx   xx x
         x xxxxx xxxxxxx xx x
         x            xx xx x
         x xxxxxxxxxx xx    x 
         xxxxxxxxxxxxSxxxxxxx

 Finding a way through the maze, S is the starting 6 12. And ends at E, 0 18.

 import java.util.*;
 import java.io.*;

 public class mazeSolver {
boolean wall = false;
char[][] maze;
boolean solved;


public mazeSolver(char[][] in_maze) {
    maze = in_maze;
}

public void findPath(int row, int col) {
    if (maze[row][col] == 'E') {
        solved = true;
        return;
    }

    maze[row][col] = 'b';

    if (maze[row + 1][col] == ' ' || maze[row + 1][col] == 'E') {
        findPath(row + 1, col);
    }
    else if (maze[row][col + 1] == ' ' || maze[row][col + 1] == 'E') {
        findPath(row, col + 1);
    }
    else if (maze[row - 1][col] == ' ' || maze[row - 1][col] == 'E') {
        findPath(row -1, col);
    }
    else if (maze[row][col - 1] == ' ' || maze[row][col - 1] == 'E') {
        findPath(row, col - 1);
    }
    else {
        wall = true;
        return;
    }

    if (wall) {
        wall = false;
        findPath(row, col);
    }

    if (solved) {
        maze[row][col] = '+';
    }

}

public void printMaze(int rows, int cols) {
    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++) {
            System.out.print(maze[i][j]);
        }

        System.out.println();
    }
}



public void solveCheck(int rows, int cols) {
    boolean solveable = false;
    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++) {
            if (maze[i][j] != '+') {
                solveable = true;
            }
            break;
        }
        break;
    }

    if(!solveable){
        System.out.println("S is unreachable");
    }
}
```

}

also this is the main class

```
      import java.util.Scanner;
       import java.io.File;

         public class ADTmaze {
           public static void main(String[] args) {
          try {
        Scanner myScanner = new Scanner(
                new File("maze.txt"));
        int numRows = myScanner.nextInt();
        int numCols = myScanner.nextInt();
        myScanner.nextLine();

        int startX = 0;
        int startY = 0;

        // New maze
        char[][] maze = new char[numRows][numCols];

        System.out.println(numRows +","+ numCols);



        for (int i = 0; i < numRows; i++) {
            String nextLine = myScanner.nextLine();
            for (int j = 0; j < numCols; j++) {
                char nextChar = nextLine.charAt(j);
                maze[i][j] = nextChar;
                System.out.print(nextChar);
            }
            System.out.println();
        }

        // Solve the maze
        mazeSolver newMaze = new mazeSolver(maze);
        System.out.println();
        newMaze.findPath(startX, startY);
        newMaze.printMaze(numRows, numCols);


        // Find the starting point
        for (int i = 0; i < numRows; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < numCols; j++) {
                if (maze[i][j] == 'S') {
                    System.out.println("Starting coordinates: "
                            + i + ", " + j);
                    startX = i;
                    startY = j;
                }
            }
        }


    } catch (Exception ex) {
        System.out.println(ex);
    }
}
```

}

Get an error, but it doesn't print the entire matrix like above orginal, and i get a error no line found. not sure where its wrong. I am not sure where the print function is going wrong

```
     20,7
    xxxxxxx
    x     x
    x xxxxx
    x xxxxx
    x      
    x xxxxx
    xxxxxxx
     java.util.NoSuchElementException: No line found
```

Comment: Remove  this line in java 

         20 7
         xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxEx
         x     x       xxxx x
         x xxxxx xxxxx   xx x
         x xxxxx xxxxxxx xx x
         x            xx xx x
         x xxxxxxxxxx xx    x 
         xxxxxxxxxxxxSxxxxxxx

 Finding a way through the maze, S is the starting 6 12. And ends at E, 0 18.

Comment: I'd suggest commenting out the try/catch in main so that you get a stack dump from the point where the exception was thrown.  One place you can get an exception is in the print/build loop if an input string is longer than the number of columns.  I'm not sure what you should do if the data file maze extends beyond the declared maze size.  Without additional directions, I'd ignore the extra characters and print a message if any of them were nonblank.

Answer (score 0):

well, for one thing your first line in maze.txt is backward, you should have it 7 20 for 7 rows (0 thru 6) and 20 columns.

also, you need to find the location of S before you do the recursion, so move that chunk of code higher up.

finally, you need to find the dimensions of the array inside mazeSolver, and then test the two if test blocks that have row+1 and col+1 - that is, if you start at the bottom at 6,12 and then try and get maze[7,12] element (row+1) your program will bomb.